# Frequency of Mpemba Effect

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

What are the chances of warm water freezing faster than cold water? (How many percent?)

Does it have to do with container size or something in it?

Comment: Why do you believe this has anything to do with chance?  Have you read, e.g., [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect)?

Comment: so what do you say? which one of them always happens? warm or cold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phenomenon ("warm water freezing faster than cold water") is not probabilistic.  Rather, it either occurs or it doesn't depending on the precise definitions and control of all relevant conditions.

From [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect#Recent_views):

> [A reviewer for Physics World writes](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/print/2006/mar/29/does-hot-water-freeze-first), "Even if the Mpemba effect is
>   real — if hot water can sometimes freeze more quickly than cold — it
>   is not clear whether the explanation would be trivial or
>   illuminating." He pointed out that investigations of the phenomenon
>   need to control a large number of initial parameters (including type
>   and initial temperature of the water, dissolved gas and other
>   impurities, and size, shape and material of the container, and
>   temperature of the refrigerator) and need to settle on a particular
>   method of establishing the time of freezing, all of which might affect
>   the presence or absence of the Mpemba effect.

Answer (score -4):

This article explains the randomness of the phenomenon:[New Explanation](https://www.mdpi.com/660974). Initially-hot water has lost much of its ordered clustering (higher entropy) and, if the cooling time is sufficiently short, this will not be fully re-attained before freezing. Experiments on the low-density water around macromolecules have shown that such clustering processes may take some time.Entropy reduction curves function of temperature S=f(T) appear retardation (lagging) relative to entropy growth curves.At any temperature point T the entropy S=mclnT during cooling is more than this during heating.The water after was heated and recooled at the initial temperature,has more entropy than before it was heated.This means that molecules have now the same average kinetic energy,but thermal motion before heating was more oriented by the structure mentioned above.Recooling random collisions are more possible leading to faster temperature’s reduction.

Comment: Please don not post verbatim the same answer to multiple questions, instead make us moderators aware, that the questions are identical witn a custom flag.